# Expresión lambda en delegado

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegados

Tengo un delegado en una clase

```
    public delegate void TotalesDelegate(int steps);
    public TotalesDelegate TotalesCallBack { get; set; } = null;
```

Entiendo que este es un delegado que recibe un entero. Pero se deja null por defecto ya que podría usarse o no.

Cuando se instancia el objeto de la clase y se setea el delegado se hace asi:

```
TotalesCallBack = steps => session[SESSION_TOTALES] = steps;
```

No entiendo, como steps sin estar declarado en ningun lado se auto determina como entero. Se que es porque el delegado recibe un entero, pero no entiendo como.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: No se si entiendo tu duda. En `TotalesCallback` lo que se almacena es un metodo, que lo que hace es asignar a `session[SESSION_TOTALES]` el valor entero que se le pase. Es decir, si haces `TotalesCallback(3)`, tras ejecutarlo en `session[SESSION_TOTALES]` tendras un 3

Comment: Hola Pikoh, antes que nada gracias por tu ayuda. Claro eso mismo pense! sin embargo con f10 fui recorriendo y pasos después de la instancia del objeto. Sesión sigue con el mismo valor con el que inicio. Se hace un llamado a TotalesCallback(8) pero la session nunca cambia a 8. Otra cosa que veo es que TotalesCallback no tiene desarrollo y es void.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver. Si la variable de sesion no cambia sera otro el problema yo creo. Puedes hacer una prueba. Crea una variable int y prueba a modificar la lambda para que en lugar de asignar steps a la sesion,se lo asigne a la variable esa. Veras como si funciona

Comment: [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uQScXR) te dejo un ejemplo de como funciona.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Pikoh, Tenes toda la razón, la lógica del código es tal cual la comentaste, el hecho de que no funciona es por otra cosa.
Gracias a tu ayuda resolví mi problema.
Saludos.